# how to read xlsx file using pyspark without help of pandas

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using this code to read the XLSX file in my local PC. but I couldn't read that file and I am using "com.crealytics.spark.excel" library also.

```
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("test") \
    .master("local[0]") \
    .getOrCreate()

empFile = "C:/Users/Dev/Downloads/SAMPLE.xlsx"

employeesDF = sqlContext.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("sheetName", "Sheet1").option("useHeader", "true").option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false").option("inferSchema", "false").option("location", empFile).option("addColorColumns", "False").load()

employeesDF.createOrReplaceTempView("EMP")

expLevel = sqlContext.sql("Select * from EMP")
expLevel.show()
```

if I run this code I got the error like this

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o35.load.
> : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class

Comment: sounds like a version mismatch, which spark version are you using?

Comment: am using version 3.0.0